# Securing AGS output, cache, and jobs folders

Tags: arcgis-server, security

ArcGIS Server (for .NET) generates images, etc. in **arcgisoutput**, **arcgiscache**, and **arcgisjobs** folders. Can the AGS security system (specifically, token-based) be used to secure these folders in the same manner as the REST API? Or do they require a separate strategy? I've pored over the documentation but have found nothing specific to this aspect of AGS security.

Comment: I may be off-base but I think I have used authenticated user for folder designations at the IIS level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Securing the cache directory](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/0093/009300000080000000.htm) - this might help in part. It's got nothing to do with token security. Just a way of accessing cache tiles with no virtual directory.